# Reset form on clicking event in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms

Can any one suggest an easy way to reset or reload an HTML form on click event in AngularJS?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There's plenty of information on this available online, and on SO too.

Comment: See first example at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular.copy({},yourform) to copy empty array to your form object as below

```
$scope.resetForm = function(form) {
     angular.copy({}, form);
}
```

Html

```
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="myForm.myName" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="myForm.adress" />
    <input type="button" value="reset" ng-click="resetForm(myForm)" />
</form>
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11182/)