# Reset Specific Input Field Validation After Submitted AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, laravel

Please help, How to reset validations specifically input fields when I checked `checkbox`.

I used

```
$scope.patient.ngModelName.$dirty = false; 
$scope.patient.ngModelName.$pristine = true; 
$scope.patient.ngModelName.$submitted = false;
```

and it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117253/reset-form-on-clicking-event-in-angularjs/44117585#44117585

Answer (score 0):

To reset a input field you just

```
 form['modelName'].$setPristine();
```

This link will be useful: [use pristine](http://plnkr.co/edit/815Bml?p=preview)